# How to throw exceptions on search methods in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-data-jpa repositories for database operations. I want to throw exceptions if object doesn't exists in database for all methods in my repositories. For example Consider the following method in `OrderRepository`

```
findByCustomerAndPayment(Customer customer, Payment payment);
```

I want to query all orders based on customerId and paymentId. Both the objects are neccessry in the above query. But spring-data-rest returns null if I gave cutomerId doesn't exists in database. I expect spring-data-rest to throw exception if object doesn't exists in database.

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can change the method prefix from 'find' to 'get', https://tuhrig.de/find-vs-get/

Comment: Check @Salah's solution below. Best solution.

Answer (score 14):

You just need **orElseThrow**

```
orderRepository.findByCustomerAndPayment(customer, payment).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("customer", "id", customer.getId()));
```

Comment: This is the best solution i think. 
First devclare the method as Optional<{Type}> and then use this. Thanks Salah.

Comment: I think the same but, anyone knows the opposite? Throwing a exception if exists?

Comment: @ghossio bit late to party - why would you want it? only thing I can think of right now is having a count and conditionally throwing exception but there is no usage of optional if that was what you needed

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Java 8, you can use `Optional<Order>` as the return type of the repository method. If the repository method returns an empty `Optional` calling get on it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`. Otherwise there is no support for throwing exceptions by repository methods if there are no results.

```
try {
  Optional<Order> result = repository.findByCustomerAndPayment(customer,payment);
  Order order = result.get();
} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
  // do something with the exception
}
```

Comment: Handling RuntimeExceptions should not be a good way, especially if you can avoid them. Optional class has different methods to check and to perform actions if element is missing or it's present. Example: order.orElseThrow(...), order.orElse(...), order.ifPresent(), etc...

Answer (score 4):

You can make custom repository implementation like below:

```
public interface OrderRepositoryCustom {
    Order findByCustomerAndPaymentRequired(Customer customer, Payment payment);
}

public class OrderRepositoryImpl implements OrderRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired 
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Override
    public Order findByCustomerAndPaymentRequired(Customer customer, Payment payment) {
        Order o = orderRepository.findByCustomerAndPayment(customer, payment);
        if(o == null) {
            throw new IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException(1);
        }
        return o;
    }

}
```

Your `OrderRepository` interface should extend customized:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long>, OrderRepositoryCustom {
    Order findByCustomerAndPayment(Customer customer, Payment payment);
}
```

*Edited*

As `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` is `RuntimeException`, then no need to `throws` declaration - i fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Optional` together with `orElseThrow`.

```
Order findByCustomerAndPayment(Customer customer, Payment payment);

default Order findByCustomerAndPaymentOrThrow(Customer customer, Payment payment) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(findByCustomerAndPayment(customer, payment)).orElseThrow();
};
```